# How to use boolean negation in "where:"?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to write a query to retrieve posts of all categories but the category "Personal".

I have the following code to retrieve all posts which are tagged as "Personal", so I tried to use " ! " and " not " to get which are not "Personal".

```
{% assign sorted-posts = site.posts | where: "categories", "Personal" %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

So, I tried this:

```
{% assign sorted-posts = site.posts | not where: "categories", "Personal" %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% assign sorted-posts = site.posts | ! where: "categories", "Personal" %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

It didn't work. How can I use " not " or " ! " in Liquid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `post.categories` is an array, you can check if it contains a certain value with `contains` filter. eg : `if post.categories contains "Personal"`

The `unless` control flow tag, which is equivalent to `"if not"` can now be used to print all posts that are not from "personal" category.

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% unless post.categories contains "Personal" %}
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```